# Data standardization, across samples or across features?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have 4 samples data with 5 features, as an array, `data`.

[image]

```
 import numpy as np


data = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0],
                 [1,1,1,1,0],
                 [1,0,0,0,0]])

print (data)
```

`n_samples, n_features = data.shape = (4,5)`

When I apply StandardScaler on it as follows, does it standardize the data across features or across samples?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
result = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
print (result)

[[ 0.57735027  1.          1.          1.          0.        ]
 [-1.73205081 -1.         -1.         -1.          0.        ]
 [ 0.57735027  1.          1.          1.          0.        ]
 [ 0.57735027 -1.         -1.         -1.          0.        ]]
```

What's the best practice of data standardization in machine learning, across samples or across features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of StandardScaler/MinMaxScaler the data are scaled across features and this is the best common practice

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0],
                 [1,1,1,1,0],
                 [1,0,0,0,0]])

result = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
result

array([[ 0.57735027,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [-1.73205081, -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.57735027,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.57735027, -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,  0.        ]])
```

you can verify it by your self

```
(data - data.mean(0))/data.std(0).clip(1e-5)

array([[ 0.57735027,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [-1.73205081, -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.57735027,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.57735027, -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: `0,0,0,0,0` are features of the 2nd sample. However, the standardized values are not all zeros (expected if calculation is across the features) for this sample. So, your answer is calculating across samples, for example, all zeros are samples of the last feature.

Comment: no, the standardize second row must be not all zeros.... for the first columns and second rows u have (0-mean_first_col)/std_first_col which is not 0... check it with my second implementation

Comment: `np.mean([0,0,0,0,0]) = 0`. `np.std([0,0,0,0,0]) = 0`. So, `(0-0)/0 = 0`.

Comment: np.mean([0.577, -1.73, 0.577, 0.577]) = mean_first_col != 0 ... np.std([0.577, -1.73, 0.577, 0.577]) = std_first_col != 0 ... data.mean(0) is the mean column-wise

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html standardize FEATURES and not samples

Comment: yes, `data.mean(0) is the mean column-wise`. So, you standardzed across the columns, right?

Comment: data across the columns are samples but not features, is not it?

Comment: columns and features are the same things. sklearn scaler computes standardization at columns/features level... I think you understand the logic

Comment: yes, I think now we are on the same track ahah don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)